# Resizing of a Raphael canvas on orientation changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, raphael

I have the following problem:
I create a Raphael canvas in a div. This happens as soon as the page is loaded and the initRadar() function is called:

```
var r;
var paper;
var c;
function initRadar(){
    r = $( "#circ" );
    paper = Raphael("circ", r.width(), r.height());
    c = paper.circle(r.width()/2, r.height()/2, r.height()/2-2);
    $(window).on("orientationchange",function(){
        //redraw(); // <--- the way I wanted it
        setTimeout(function(){ redraw(); }, 300); // <--- *yuck*
    }); 
}
```

This functions perfectly so far. My problem starts when the orientation of the viewport changes. I thought I could add an event handle to the window, which fires, when the orientation changes and redraw the content. And it works... kind of. I wanted to call the second function:

```
function redraw(){
    c.remove();
    c = paper.circle(r.width()/2, r.height()/2, r.height()/2-2);
}
```

Whenever the orientation changes, this function redraws the content. And this also works... almost. The problem is, I have a race condition. Even though the orientation change event fired, the #circ div still has the old size and position. This leads to the strange effect, that when the viewport is in portrait mode, the landscape circle is drawn and vice versa.

My current solution is to use the timeout function (*yuck*), to wait a few ms so that the layout is done before I draw the circle. It works, but it is ugly and I don't want to have such a hack in my code.

Can someone point me in the direction how to solve this problem correctly?